# How to customise community generic error pages

Tags: community, error, customer-community, lightning-community, site.com

I have a community using URL:

```
https://xxx-mydomain.cs83.force.com/community/s/
```

When I remove the `/community/s/` I get a salesforce branded error page.

[image]

I want the generic Salesforce error page to be branded like the rest of the customer community.

I have created branded `visualforce pages` and configured them in the `Site Error Pages` settings.

I've also created an additional `Site` which does not have a `folder` so it's hosting from the root:

```
https://xxx-mydomain.cs83.force.com/
```

And I have configured the branded `visualforce pages` in the `Site Error Pages` settings there too.

Yet I am still seeing the Salesforce branded error pages.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I remove all Salesforce branded from error pages?

Comment: Please check below setting in Community Workspaces

 1. Open Community Workspaces or Community Management.
 2. Click   Administration | Preferences. 
 3. Select Use custom Visualforce error pages, then click Save.

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni thanks, but that did not solve it

Comment: This is a know bug and there's a workaround for it:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eav5QAA&title=when-a-path-that-is-outside-of-a-domain-s-custom-urls-path-prefixes-is-accessed-on-a-domain-that-does-not-have-a-root-site-salesforce-s-generic-down

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for it:

1. Create Custom Visualforce Page and override existing error pages setting using our VF page.

- Go to Setup > Sites and Domains > Sites > Select your community by clicking the community name.
- Go to Error Page section > Click Page Page Assignment button and assign your custom VF Error page to a different Error Condition.

3. Edit existing Visualforce error pages

- CommunitiesLogin (Authorization Required Page)
- BandwidthExceeded  (Limit Exceeded Page)
- InMaintenance (Maintenance Page)
- FileNotFound  (Page Not Found Page)
- Exception (Generic Error Page)

More details you can find here: https://salesforceprofs.com/custom-community-error-page/